# Contains Class Element Identifier for Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to find an alternative to `by.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"favorites-button-icon")]')` but I can't seem to find an identifier in Protractor specifically for matching by 'contains class'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`by.css`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css) locator:

```
element(by.css(".classname"));  // or $(".classname")
```

Or, there is also a [`by.className`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.className):

```
element(by.className("classname"));
```

Note that both these options are more reliable than the `by.xpath` approach you've presented. With this XPath, you would also get elements having, for instance, `favorites-button-icon-something-else` or `something-favorites-button-icon` classes which you want to avoid.

Comment: I understand your point but what if I want to find anything that contains that class text, irrelevant of what else is there? That is my current issue, which to solve I am ending up using XPath for. I use by.css quite a lot for the purpose you mentioned though. Mainly the issue is that with Protractor I can't seem to get only the concatenated (child) element, as the '/' is giving an error and I'm ending up using '//' which finds all, but still I would like to avoid XPath anyway.

Comment: @zalow517 yeah, it would check for specific classes regardgless of other classes an element might have. For example, it would pick `<div class="test smth else">` if you would use `$(".smth")` or `$(".else")` or `$(".test")` or `$("test.smth")` or `$("test.else")` etc. you got the point. Note that if, sometimes you have a strict class match, you may always do `$('[class="test smth else"]')`. We can also look into your use case specifically if you need help there. Thanks.

Comment: As it turns out, your last comment solved my issues as for some reason I've always had the impression that `by.css` searches specifically for the term entered only, but I just tried it out and my use-case is now working as intended with `by.css`. Thank you :)